# Derivative() or diff() in SymPy ODE?

Tags: sympy, ode, derivative, dsolve

Is there a good reason to use `Derivative` instead of `diff` in the definition (and solution) of an ODE in Sympy? `diff` seems to do the job just fine:

[image: Solution of a simple ODE]

Comment: According to the docs, and examples, `diff`, `f(x).diff` and `Derivative` all do the same thing, with possible minor differences in syntax.  Look at the `type(diff(f(x),x,2))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`diff` is a "wrapper" method that it is going to instantiate the `Derivative` class. So, doing this:

```py
from sympy import *
expr = x**2
expr.diff(x)

# out: 2*x
```

is equivalent to do:

```py
Derivative(expr, x).doit()

# out: 2*x
```

However, the `Derivative` class might be useful to delay the evaluation of a derivative. For example:

```py
Derivative(expr, x)

# out: Derivative(x**2, x)
```

But the same thing can also be achieved with:

```py
expr.diff(x, evaluate=False)

# out: Derivative(x**2, x)
```

So, to answer your question, in the example you provided there is absolutely no difference in using `diff` vs `Derivative`.

If `expr.diff(variable)` can be evaluated, it will return an instance of `Expr` (either a symbol, a number, multiplication, addition, power operation, depending on `expr`). Otherwise, it will return an object of type `Derivative`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Derivative` object represents an unevaluated derivative. It will never evaluate, for example:

```py
>>> Derivative(x**2, x)
Derivative(x**2, x)
```

`diff` is a function which always tries to evaluate the derivative. If the derivative in question cannot be evaluated, it just returns an unevaluated `Derivative` object.

```py
>>> diff(x**2, x)
2*x
```

Since undefined functions are always things whose derivatives won't be evaluated, `Derivative` and `diff` are the same.

```py
>>> diff(f(x), x)
Derivative(f(x), x)
>>> Derivative(f(x), x)
Derivative(f(x), x)
```

There's only a difference between the two in cases where the derivative can be evaluated. For ODEs, this means that it generally doesn't matter, except maybe if you have something like the following that you don't want expanded

```py
>>> diff(x*f(x), x)
x*Derivative(f(x), x) + f(x)
>>> Derivative(x*f(x), x)
Derivative(x*f(x), x)
```